# Can I use an old router to “convert” a WPA2-Enterprise to WPA2-Personal?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I recently moved into a college dorm that provides WiFi with WPA2-Enterpise+PEAP - every student has an individual username and password to connect to the university network. Amazon Echo, does not support WPA2-Enterprise, only WPA2-Personal. To top that, the WiFi signals are a bit sketchy too. Fortunately, we have an ethernet port available in each room.

Is it possible, to use a router to connect to the university network over ethernet(which uses WPA2-Enterprise + PEAP), and then connect to the router using WPA2-Personal?

If yes, what do I need for this setup? and How do I set this thing up? I have intermediate computer skills.

Comment: Ethernet does not actually support WPA2-Enterprise.  What the actual configuration is based on that fact is not clear (it’s not WPA2 which is only applicable to 802.11)

Comment: Just to be clear, WPA2-Enterprise is specific to Wi-Fi. WPA2-Enterprise is built on top of 802.1X (note: X is NOT a wildcard or placeholder here), which was originally an authentication protocol for wired Ethernet. Are you saying that, in order to connect to the wired Ethernet network in your dorm room, you have to set up 802.1X authentication?

Comment: Yes. to connect to the ethernet port, the authentication is 802.1X+PEAP

Comment: Apologies for the lame mistakes and obscure/ommited details if any, I am a noob at this. Would love to provide any/all information for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to set up a device to act as a NAT gateway, and have its WAN/public Ethernet port run an 802.1X supplicant (or, if its WAN/public port is Wi-Fi in client STA mode, have that port run a WPA2-Enterprise supplicant). You could have that same box also have a private LAN or AP-mode WLAN port that doesn't require authentication, and connect your non-802.1X-capable devices to that.

The fact that you would have all your traffic going through NAT should obscure, at least from the casual observer, the fact that the traffic is actually coming from multiple client devices. Please note, though, that algorithms and probably products do exist to try to discover if NAT is running on a given device, based on the fingerprints of the traffic going to/from the suspected NAT's public IP address. So if your college's network admins are sophisticated, they could detect what you're doing. Also note that if you start publishing a wireless network, even if you hide the network name, your college's network admins will still be able to detect your network and track it down to your dorm room.

Please read the acceptable use policy for your college network to make sure what you're planning on doing is okay.